# Spread or dcast and fill in counts

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2, spread, dcast

Probably a basic question.

I have a `key - value` `data.frame`(`df` below):

```
features <- paste0("f",1:5)
set.seed(1)
ids <- paste0("id",1:10)

df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(ids,function(i){
  data.frame(id = i, feature = sample(features,3,replace = F))
}))
```

And I want to `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::dcast` it, so that the rows are `id' the columns are` feature`, but the values are the sum of` features`for each`id`.

A simple:

```
reshape2::dcast(df, id ~ feature)
```

Doesn't achieve that. It just fills in with `feature`s and `NA`s

adding `fun.aggregate = sum` to the command above results with an error:

```
> reshape2::dcast(df, id ~ feature, fun.aggregate = sum)
Using feature as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

And tidyr::spread also results with an error:

```
tidyr::spread(df, key = id, value = feature)

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 30 rows:
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to count the features and not `sum` them. Try with the function `length`.

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = feature, 
            values_from = feature, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

Or with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), id~feature, value.var = 'feature', fun.aggregate = length)
```

In base R, using `table(df)` would give the same output.

```
table(df)

#     feature
#id     f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
#  id1   1  0  1  1  0
#  id10  1  0  1  1  0
#  id2   1  1  0  0  1
#  id3   0  1  1  1  0
#  id4   1  0  1  0  1
#  id5   1  1  0  0  1
#  id6   1  1  1  0  0
#  id7   1  0  0  1  1
#  id8   1  1  0  0  1
#  id9   0  1  0  1  1
```